# Would an LCD monitor still work if both polarized films were rotated equally?

Tags: lcd

I am making a transparent computer monitor which can only be seen when using polarized glasses. Most commercial glasses are polarized vertically but the monitor that I'm working with seems to be polarized at a 45 degree angle. I've removed the front polarized layer and the monitor works wonderfully with a pair of polarized glasses but i have to crook my head to the left in order to see it at it's brightest. I'm wondering if I could replace the back polarized layer with a horizontally polarized film in order to display my monitor best with a straight head. I can't think of a reason that this wouldn't work but I'd rather not total an LCD to try it.

Comment: Pop the lenses out of your polarized sunglasses and rotate them relative to each other and see what happens.